# linq how to build a where predicate

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I want to query an IEnumerable of shapes.  I have different kinds of shapes and they are related to a given coordinate in different ways depending on the type of shape.

for any given coordinate I would like to find it's related shapes. And I would like to use Linq to do this.  But coming unstuck through a lack of understanding. Been searching and reading for a couple of hours but I can find the correct words to get me an example of what I am trying to do. Below is some code which hopefully shows the concept of what I would like to do but clearly does not work. There must be a way of chaining these expressions - I have seen predicate builder and may use that, but I want to learn more fundamentals first.
How do I make this work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace LinqLearning
{
    public class Coordinate
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class Bounded
    {
        public Coordinate TopRight { get; set; }
        public Coordinate BottomLeft { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shape1 : Bounded
    { }
    public class Shape2 : Bounded
    { }
    public class LinqExperiments
    {
        public IEnumerable<Bounded> GetSquaresNearPoint(IEnumerable<Bounded> shapesEnumerable, Coordinate locator)
        {
            Expression<Func<Bounded, Coordinate, bool>> Shape1NearCoordinate =
                (shape, coord) => shape.TopRight.Y > coord.Y &&
                                  shape.BottomLeft.Y < coord.Y &&
                                  shape.TopRight.X == coord.X;
            Expression<Func<Bounded, Coordinate, bool>> Shape2NearCoordinate =
                (shape, coord) => shape.TopRight.Y == coord.Y &&
                                  shape.TopRight.X < coord.X + 3 &&
                                  shape.TopRight.X > coord.X - 3;


            Expression<Func<IQueryable<Bounded>, Coordinate, bool>> predicate = (shapes, coord) => Shape1NearCoordinate || Shape2NearCoordinate;

            return shapesEnumerable.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to `OR` 2 compound conditions, namely  `Shape1NearCoordinate` and `Shape2NearCoordinate`. You can do that without any `LINQ Expression` usage. Are you just using them for learning, or am I not following some finer point here?

Comment: Yes primarily for learning.  But I do have a use case and it would be nice to have these expressions as reusable.  Typically I expect one of each shape at the coordinate.  I want to get both shapes out the list of shapes in one query.

Comment: They can be `Func` itself instead of `Expression<Func>` and still be reusable. BTW, it seems like they should just be a regular function instead of any `LAMBDA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why you use `Expression`s and `IQueryable`s. I think this can be solved by just `Func<Bounded, Coordinate, bool>`:

```
    public IEnumerable<Bounded> GetSquaresNearPoint(IEnumerable<Bounded> shapesEnumerable, Coordinate locator)
    {
        Func<Bounded, Coordinate, bool> Shape1NearCoordinate =
            (shape, coord) => shape.TopRight.Y > coord.Y &&
                              shape.BottomLeft.Y < coord.Y &&
                              shape.TopRight.X == coord.X;
        Func<Bounded, Coordinate, bool> Shape2NearCoordinate =
            (shape, coord) => shape.TopRight.Y == coord.Y &&
                              shape.TopRight.X < coord.X + 3 &&
                              shape.TopRight.X > coord.X - 3;
        Func<Bounded, Coordinate, bool> predicate = (shapes, coord) => Shape1NearCoordinate(shapes, coord) || Shape2NearCoordinate(shapes, coord);
        return shapesEnumerable.Where(x => predicate(x, locator));
    }
```

Comment: I used Expressions because when I opened the bracket after 'Where' visual studio told me it wanted an Expression<Func< etc.

Comment: @John - That's only because you started with `IQueryable<>`. Why did you start with those?

Comment: @Enigmativity I ended up with IQueryable<>  because when I first tried this Vstudio gave an error saying that IEnumerable did not support where clauses but it allowed me to AsQueryable().Where - I think I was missing as Using statementmaybe and this threw me.

Comment: @John - Sounds like it. You've ended up going down a rabbit hole that you should have completely avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Why not stick to plain simple functions? No need to use `Lambda` or `Linq Expressions` when they are not really needed.

```
static bool Shape1NearCoordinate(Bounded shape, Coordinate coord) {
    return shape.TopRight.Y > coord.Y &&
            shape.BottomLeft.Y < coord.Y &&
            shape.TopRight.X == coord.X;
}

static bool Shape2NearCoordinate(Bounded shape, Coordinate coord) {
    return shape.TopRight.Y == coord.Y &&
            shape.TopRight.X < coord.X + 3 &&
            shape.TopRight.X > coord.X - 3;
}

public IEnumerable<Bounded> GetSquaresNearPoint(IEnumerable<Bounded> shapesEnumerable, Coordinate locator) {
    return shapesEnumerable.Where(shape => Shape1NearCoordinate(shape, locator) || Shape2NearCoordinate(shape, locator));
}
```